# atmosphere javascript client - reason for AtmosphereRequest#timeout

Tags: java, atmosphere

What is the reason of timeout parameter of AtmosphereRequest?

I am talking about javascript client library - see https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/jQuery.atmosphere.js-atmosphere.js-API#timeout-default--300000 where is said this:

> **Timeout**
>
> The maximum time a connection stay opened when no message (or event)
> are sent or received.

In what usecases it is useful? Why it has default value of 5 minutes (300000 ms)?

Comment: Good question. I was wondering that myself. I'm trying to think of a single reason that wouldn't be covered by another feature.